# ExpectIt: Suppress console echo

Tags: java, tomcat7, expectit

Refer: [ExpectIt : Trouble implementing a sudo -i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477489/expectit-trouble-implementing-a-sudo-i)

How can I avoid echoing all output of Expectit to my java console?

This is how I started my SSH:

```
public void connect( String host, String user, String password ) throws Exception {
    this.host = host;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
    ssh = new SSHClient();
    ssh.addHostKeyVerifier( new PromiscuousVerifier() );
    ssh.connect(host, port);
    ssh.authPassword(user, password);
    session = ssh.startSession();

    session.allocateDefaultPTY();
    shell = session.startShell();

    expect = new ExpectBuilder()
            .withOutput(shell.getOutputStream())
            .withInputs(shell.getInputStream(), shell.getErrorStream())
            .withInputFilters(removeColors(), removeNonPrintable())
            .withExceptionOnFailure()
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    String result = expect.expect( Matchers.contains( PROMPT ) ).getInput();
    consoleOut.add( result );

}
```

Now ALL results taken from Expect will echo to the console. I can take the "result" string, but it goes to tomcat console too (I'm sure I'm not send it to).

```
expect.sendLine( command );
String result = expect.expect( Matchers.contains( PROMPT ) ).getInput();
```

I'm running in a Tomcat container (web environment).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable to the command echo by sending the `stty -echo` command at the beginning of the session. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expectit-core/src/test/java/net/sf/expectit/SshLocalhostNoEchoExample.java) example.

I suggest to post questions to the ExpectIt [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/java-expectit) rather then on Stackoverflow since currently there are only a few people who are using this library.